# php multiple derived and parallel inherited classes

Tags: php, inheritance

For example I wan't to make some "base" class, and extend it as much as possible, and then make Super class that have all extended methods.

```
class Base {
 private $name;
 public function __construct($name) {
   $this->name=$name;
 }
 public function getName() {
   return $this->name;
 }
}

class ExtendA extends Base {
 private $surName;
 public function __construct($surName) {
   $this->surName=$surName;
 }
 public function getSurName() {
   return $this->surName;
 }
}

class ExtendB extends Base {
 private $lastName;
 public function __construct($lastName) {
   $this->lastName=$lastName;
 }
 public function getLastName() {
   return $this->lastName;
 }
}

class Maximal ??? {
 .... ???
}

$object=new Maximal('name','surname','lastName');

$object->getName(); // name from Base Class
$object->getSurName(); // surname from ExtendA class
$object->getLastName(); // lastname from ExtendB class
```

this already is possible if we follow line-by-line inheritance A, B ext A, C ext B.
but what to do if I wan't parallel or order of extends is unknown?
maybe I need to use autoload?

Comment: PHP does not support multiple inheritance. once you branch off parallel descendants from a common ancestor, you cannot merge them again later. Such sibling "incest" is generally a very bad idea in OOP.

Comment: @MarcB, Ok we can always follow common ancestor, but what if classes is added dynamically? (for example new feature added in a middle)

Comment: you mean take `a->b->c` and change it to `a->b->d->c`? that's possible

Comment: Yes, exactly, but in that case I need to change c class to "extends d" instead of "extends b". how to do this dynamically?

Comment: you can't. not without meddling inside php's innards. consider what'd happen if you'd already instanciated a `c` object, THEN when and fiddled with the inheritance change? If you have to modify objects like that on the fly, then your system needs to be scrapped and rebuilt.

Comment: okay, so in this moment answer is : just follow common ancestor.

Comment: lol sibling incest @MarcB , only on SO :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Marc B

```
 PHP does not support multiple inheritance.
```

But real solution is create code with PSR-4 - like style and using autoload (composer or bootstrap style).

And then We can create a lot of expendable staff.

Also inheritance can be "visually" changed to static methods.